# Why Visual C++ not accept generic and non-generic interfaces with the same name?

Tags: visual-c++, generics, c++-cli

I have problem with generic and non-generic interfaces with the same name.

My code:

```
public interface class IPacked {
    // Methods
    void PackFromDouble(double realNumber);
    double ToDouble( );
};

generic<typename T> public interface class IPacked : public IPacked {
    // Property
    property T PackedValue {
        virtual T get( );
        virtual void set(T value);
    }
};
```

I know that, it can be compiled. My friend use it in old team project. 
However, this problem does not exist in the functions.

Comment: I know(guess) they're in the same namespace, but still have you tried with the namespace-qualified name anyway? (`generic<typename T> public interface class IPacked : public MyNamespace::IPacked`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not supported because of C++ language rules.  From the [C++/CLI Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-372.htm), chapter 31.1:

> A generic type shall not have the same name as any other generic type, template, class, delegate, function,
>   object, enumeration, enumerator, namespace, or type in the same scope (C++ Standard 3.3), except as
>   specified in 14.5.4 of the C++ Standard. Except that a generic function can be overloaded either by nongeneric
>   functions with the same name or by other generic functions with the same name, a generic name
>   declared in namespace scope or in class scope shall be unique in that scope.

Chapter 14.5.4 of the C++ Standard talks about partial template specializations, nothing that will help you here.

As a workaround, you could consider declaring the interfaces in a C# assembly and adding a reference to it.  Or using different namespaces, much like System::Collections::IEnumerable vs System::Collections::Generic::IEnumerable<>.